# Consume updates from a separate library

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Just wondering if anyone had any advice on this matter -

I have a server developed as a class library (in a Visual Studio project of its own) that downloads, parses and sends google cloud message notifications whenever certain rules are triggered. I also have a separate project that acts as a front end, done using WPF and MVVM.

At the minute, I have an event in the server class library for whenever a notification is triggered, and in the front end I hook up an event handler to it so whenever a notification is sent, it gets 'sent' to the front end and displayed... but is the the best way to handle something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar situation in one of my projects where I had to send events to other parts of the application. Trying to keep MVVM pattern as pure as I can, I ended up using MVVM Messenger/Mediator from MVVM Foundation.

Mediator explanation:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/

MVVM Foundation link:

http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/

You can use the mediator to send objects from one viewmodel to another as well. I've used it in situations where my Listbox selection would change. I would send the newly selected item to another viewmodel for further processing.

I am not including any examples since the link has them. Let me know in the comments if you want me to show you an example of my implementation and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Ah right, I'm using something similar to a mediator in my front end app to send the notifications to the appropriate ViewModel, the only problem is getting the notifications from the library - 

project (FrontEnd) ->
  Front End Client

 <-- How to pass messages between here? -->

project (NotificationGenerator)
  NotificationServer

Comment: In your NotificationGenerator you would fire your Mediator Notification (Mediator.NotifyColleagues...). Both your server dll and your front end have to reference the same instance of the Mediator class for the registration to work, so you could place it in server library. I have never done that part, so it will be a bit of experimentation...

Comment: Yeah, I wasx thinking of making the mediator a separate library too, that way they NotificationGenerator registers with it as the sender, sends the update and it should hopefully be pushed to the corresponding ViewModel if all goes well :)